# Compactor ram won't quit going down

Tags: kitchens, appliances

I've got a trash compactor with ... issues.

I came home from work to a report from my kids that it was "broken", and was making a horrible noise. All I knew was that the ram wasn't moving at all, and if you pushed the button the motor would make noise until someone manually turned it off.

I opened up the bottom, and one problem was immediately obvious: The plastic portion of the main ram gear had sheared completely into two pieces.

[image: Two halves of a ram gear]

A week later (since the Christmas holiday was in the middle) I had a new ram gear kit, replaced the broken part, and slapped it back together.

Unfortunately, now what its doing is that when you start it, the ram gets pushed down as far as it can go, but the motor just keeps going. It makes a horrible noise once its at the bottom, until you turn the compactor off. At that point turning it back on does cause the motor to raise the ram back up until it reaches the proper stop position, like its supposed to.

From the description I was given, it sounds like this was probably how it was behaving when that gear sheared in half. So it looks like I've solved an effect, but not the cause of the problem.

I tried looking online, and found a lot of advice about what to do *if the ram won't stop at the top*, but nothing about what to do if it won't stop **at the bottom**.

I did check the plastic "ram stops" (a new pair came with my kit, so why not?), but the original ones look fine to me.

So what should a person check if the ram motor doesn't want to detect that its done going down and stop/reverse at the bottom, but it otherwise works perfectly fine going both down and up?

---

Update: I ordered and replaced the direction switch, and its still doing the same thing.

[image: Compactor Direction Switch]

So the problem's not that. To reiterate, it goes down fine like it always has. Then when it gets to the bottom, it tries to keep going and I hear a much higher-pitched and louder noise from the motor, until I turn the compactor off. Turning it back on causes the compactor to come back up like normal.

---

Update 2:

I did a lot more research, and found the following:

- A whole new compactor would be more than $1k. This is probably because almost nobody buys them anymore. Could be nobody makes them anymore either.
- They aren't that complicated. About the only things that can go wrong electronically are the directional switch, the start/stop switch, and the centrifugal switch.
- The centrifugal switch is part of the motor, and can't easily be serviced separately.

Realistically, of the 3 the only one that can cause the issue I'm having with it not reversing is the centrifugal switch, but the general advice is to check everything else first, since the switch in the motor can't really be checked.

So I've replaced the direction switch (kinda had to. I wasn't careful...), and the start-stop switch tests OK, so that leaves me with the motor's centrifugal switch. If that doesn't work, well I either spend a ridiculous amount of money for a simple device nobody wants anymore, or join the 21st century and embrace the compactor-free lifestyle.

Comment: There is a limit switch which detects when the ram has reached maximum intended pressure. Apparently when you reassembled that was set incorrectly orr otherwise blocked from operating. Can't give you any more detail than that.

Comment: ...or it just went bad (causing my clueless kids to wonder what that horrible noise was, until the plastic gear sheared in half).

Comment: @keshlam - Re-checked all the other plastic ram parts (ram stops and power nuts) and they look fine. So new ram limit switch on order. Watch this space for another week I guess.

Comment: Yep, this is a controls problem. Good luck with the switch.

Comment: @keshlam - Is that switch the part I pictured above, or something else? I googled "trash compactor limit switch", and all I'm getting is that "direction switch" part.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally got this fixed, so I thought I'd post the answer that hopefully would have helped me.

There are 4 switches in compactors, all of which being moving parts, can wear out/go bad.

1. The three-way directional switch.
2. The on/off switch
3. Door (aka "safety") switch
4. Internal motor switches

You can check the first 3 with a multimeter, but the last is/are inside the compactor motor. So the strategy is to check all the others first, and if they are all good, try replacing the motor<sup>*</sup>.

The directional switch, if it goes bad you'll likely see either the compactor refuse to start at all, or not want to stop when it gets to the top.

If either the on switch or the door switch go bad, most likely the compactor will refuse to start at all.

If an internal motor switch goes bad, then you can see what I saw: the compactor going all the way to the bottom and then just trying to keep going until turned off. According to what I read, a failure on a switch in there can also sometimes cause the compactor ram to just go up and down continually.

So I my case, I got a multimeter and tested the other 3 switches, and they were all working properly (including of course the one I replaced after I accidentally broke the old one). Since that left the motor, I ordered a replacement for that, and when installed, that fixed the problem.

So the ultimate answer was: **Bad switch internal to the motor.** The switch itself was not really user-serviceable, but a new motor fixed the problem.

---

<sup>* - [This YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KIx3YKrmBs) I found very helpful for explaining the troubleshooting process.</sup>